# Como aumentar o tamanho de um vetor mantendo sua forma original? MATLAB

Tags: array, matlab

Eu tenho dois vetores, um tem vetor X de 729 elementos e o outro vetor Y 429 elementos, porém eu precisava montar um gráfico (vetor X, vetor Y), porém eles têm tamanho diferentes e isso não é possível

Então eu precisava saber se existe algum modo de "alongar" o tamanho do vetor Y de 429 para 729 elementos, mas queria que ele mantivesse a forma original e conseguisse fazer essa transformação

Comment: Acabei de perceber que você deve explicar o que quer dizer com forma original!
Você diz valores correspondentes?

Answer (score 1):

A resposta para essa pergunta é [**Interpolação!**](https://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/interpolation.html).

Porém, você não deve alongar a valor de Y, mas sim diminuir o de X! O motivo disso é que reduzir o número de valores em geral tem mais precisão que o contrário. 
Obviamente, interpolação existe pois nem sempre isso é possível. Dito isso, seguem dois exemplos.

Aqui uso a função [`interp1`](https://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/interp1.html), mas tem outras no link que coloquei antes.
E um comentário **bem importante**: Existem muitas maneiras de fazer esta interpolacão, além de outras funcões você pode usar ou não o par (X,Y). Aqui o fiz o mais fácil pra mim dado o seu enunciado!

```
%dados
a=1:10
a=
 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
%Aumentar
b=interp1(a,linspace(min(a),max(a),19))
b=
 1 1.5 2 2.5 3 3.5 4 4.5 5 5.5 6 6.5 7 7.5 8 8.5 9 9.5 10
%diminuir
b=interp1(a,linspace(min(a),max(a),4))
b= 1 4 7 10
```

Veja que os números foram selecionados pra serem *bonitos para esta resposta*, mas a função funciona com qualquer valor.

**Um outro comentário importante** é saber como os números são distribuídos. Esse método funciona bem quando os valores são distribuídos de maneira homogênea (1,2,3,4), mas pode dar problemas num outro caso (1,4,5,6). Interpolação é uma coisas complicada, quando estiver com mais tempo talvez aumente a discussão com exemplos rápidos pros dois casos e mais métodos.

Comment: dei +1, mas tome cuidado com esse tipo de exemplo ele só vai funcionar direito para um vetor sequencial como demonstrado na var ´a´